# Retract a flag for a post that was deleted not due to the flag?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-questions, retracted-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159481/how-to-prevent-android-from-dying-even-when-battery-percentage-is-0) (deleted):

[image: Flag Image]

The problem is, tho the question was deleted already, the flag was not automatically removed, and is unlikely to be aged away because it's a **special mod ♦ flag**. And I am not able to retract it because question is deleted. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you care about retracting it?

Comment: @yivi Because **special mod ♦ flag**s do not age away (at least as far as I know), and it will be forever pending.

Comment: @yivi because this would decrease moderator load?

Comment: A mod will still look into it, even if the question is deleted. Chances are they'll mark as helpful and move on.